# TypeError at compile for public mapping of address ==> uint?

Tags: compilation, error

Maybe this is really obvious but for some reason I can't shake this error. At compile I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is uint256)
        voteType[msg.sender] = 2;
        ^------^
Compilation failed. See above.
```

The indexed expression is a mapping to a type (`uint`) which should be all good.

Relevant code:

```
function castVote (uint voteType) canVote {
//        require (voteType[msg.sender] == 0);
        if (voteType == 2) {//2 here meaning "Real" account.
        count[upForVote].voteReal++;
        voteType[msg.sender] = 2;
        }
        if (voteType == 1) {//1 here meaning "Fake" acount.
        count[upForVote].voteFake++;
        voteType[msg.sender] = 1;
        }
        voteInProgress[msg.sender] = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add declaration of `voteType` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function accepts a parameter called `voteType`, and it's a `uint`. So you can't index into it, because it's not an `array` or a `mapping`.

My guess is that elsewhere you declared a state variable also called `voteType`, but it's being shadowed by the parameter name in this function.

One convention in these cases is to use a leading underscore to differentiate, although that's usually for the case where both variables have the same type:

```
function castVote (uint _voteType) canVote {
    if (_voteType == 2) {  //2 here meaning "Real" account.
        count[upForVote].voteReal++;
        voteType[msg.sender] = 2;
    }
    if (_voteType == 1) {  //1 here meaning "Fake" acount.
        count[upForVote].voteFake++;
        voteType[msg.sender] = 1;
    }
    voteInProgress[msg.sender] = true;
}
```